# Defining inputs during model training, Functional API in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the Functional API in TensorFlow (https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) to build a deep learning model. So, this is my model:

```
first_inputs = Input(shape=(100, ))
first_dense = Dense(1, )(first_inputs)
second_input = Input(shape=(1, ))
merge = concatenate([first_dense, second_input])
output = Dense(1, )(merge)
model = Model(inputs=[first_inputs, second_input], outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer=ada_grad, loss='binary_crossentropy',
           metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I use train_test_split as you see:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.01, random_state=42)
```

How can I use model.fit here and say first_inputs and second_input are these columns in x_train? How can I use model.evaluate and say first_inputs and second_input are these columns in x_train?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say that. Multiple inputs should be presented to `fit` as lists of arrays. E.g:

```
X = np.random.randn(1234, 101)
X1, X2 = X[:,:100], X[:, 100]
Y = np.random.randn(1234, 1)
model.fit([X1, X2], Y)
```